# Console application to import excel data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, bulk-import

I am using this code to import data from an Excel tab sheet into SQL Server.

In one Excel tab, we have **100,000** records, but the code only imports around **49,000** records.

In a second tab, we have around **50,000** records, but the code imports only around **23,000** records.

No error occurs, and it just move to next tab to import, as we have around 18 Excel tab sheets to import.

Does anyone have any idea? What's causing this and what could be the issue in my code?

Thanks guys for reading the post.

```
using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
{
    // Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Landing Page$] where [Landing Page Unique ID] <> ''", excelConnection))
    {
        excelConnection.Open();

        using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE tblName", con);
                    con.Open();
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblName";
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[field names]", "field names");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[field names]", "field names");
                    // etc                                

                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 300;
                    // Wait
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dReader);

                    con.Close();                                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start debugging to make sure your "Select * FROM [Landing Page$]..." returns the number of rows you are expecting.

Comment: After looking at @Kevin's option, you can also adjust your timeout to see if that is an issue. Also, run the import through the SQL Export Import Tool, it will highlight issues quite quickly too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017